# Primary Key in Access

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

I should create a database on ms-acces. I uploaded the relational database schema. I've created the tables for **employee,department,dept_locations,project and dependent**.I've assigned the relationships of these. But I don't understand the **works_on** part.
How can i assign 2 primary keys to a table? What should I do?

[Relational Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RINw.png)

Comment: Create a _unique index_ having these two fields. Each of these will be a foreign key to table Project and Employee, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is called a composite primary key.  In MS Access, the way you get this is by holding down the Ctrl Key while clicking each field in the primary key.

Here is a [tutorial](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/creating-composite-keys-tutorial-for-ms-access).